# Importing html form values into a python file

Tags: python, html

I have a front end for a python operation, developed in html5, from which its taking the necessary inputs. I am not able to pass the inputs to the python code. I have tried using cgi, but it just prints my python code on the browser. Please help.

My html code index.html:

```
`<body>
<form name="inputs" action="../testProj/testcgipy.py" method="get">
Enter name: <input type="text" name="tbox"> <input type="submit" 
value="Submit">
</form>
</body>`
```

My python code testcgipy.py:

```
import cgi
form= cgi.FieldStorage()
val= form.getvalue('tbox')

print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
print "<html>"
print "<head>"
print "<title>Hello  CGI Program</title>"
print "</head>"
print "<body>"
print "<h2>Hello %s </h2>" % (val)
print "</body>"
print "</html>"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're better off using a proper HTTP server for your application. [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/), [bottle](https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/) etc are great lightweight solutions.

A proof of concept for your needs:

```py
from bottle import request, route, template, redirect, run

@route('/')
def home():
    html = '''
    <form method='get' action='/query'>
        Enter name: <input name='name'>
        <br>
        <button>Send</button>
    </form>
    '''
    return template(html)

@route('/query')
def query():
    name = request.query['name'] or None
    if not name:
        return redirect('/')
    things = get_all_things(name)

    html = '''
        % for item in things:
            <p>{{item}}</p>
        % end
    '''
    return template(html, things=things)

def get_all_things(name: str):
    return [name, 'another thing']


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

This one gives you a server reachable at `localhost:8080`:
[image: homepage]

When you submit the form:
[image: result page]